# How do I search for a string before a specific element in a Bash array?

Tags: arrays, bash

Say, I have a Bash array called `arr` with a huge number of elements. There, I am given an index of one of the elements, and I want to search for an element which contains some string *immediately* before that given element. I just want some kind of function that returns the index (or the element itself) which contains the search string. If there are multiple matches, return the first match.

```
arr=('foo' 'bar' 'baz') # the values in here are dynamic
req_index=3 # the search will be performed before the element of this index. This is unknown, i.e. dynamic as well, in the original script
search_res=$(some_magic_function $arr $req_index "search" || echo "Not found")

function some_magic_function{
  if <$3 exists in an element before ${1[$2]}>; then
    echo <index or element itself>
  else
    false
  fi
}
```

I hope I can explain the problem as clearly as possible. I'll be glad to provide additional details if needed.

Comment: Are you only supposed to search in the single element `${arr[req_index - 1]}`? Or, starting in the previous element, find some element containing the search string? Please add more details to your question, including some sample data to illustrate the problem, and some psuedo-code to describe the algorithm.

Comment: The second one actually. Any element that contains the given search string. If there exists multiple matches, return the first match.

Comment: I'll wait for you to update the question before I carry on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's just a yes/no answer:

```sh
array_search() {
    local -n __arr=$1
    local -i idx=$2
    local srch=$3
    printf '%s\n' "${__arr[@]:0:idx}" | grep -q "$srch"
}

arr=(foo bar baz qux blah)

array_search arr 4 "x"  && echo Y || echo N      # => Y
array_search arr 3 "x"  && echo Y || echo N      # => N
```

`"${__arr[@]:0:idx}"` is the elements of the array starting at offset 0 for a length of $idx